# On selecting a row in a html table, that has 1 EMPTY(" ") <td> element, instead of it , it shows me url of my own web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I know , this question may sound very very stupid
So, I am fetching a table, and I am filling my table using angular js, my table is getting filled correctly, it has 3 col. (S.no , id , image) , whenever I select a row (PRESSING EDIT BUTTON) that has no image src means ,  .So whenever I select the Image , the image src shows me the url of my own web page, Sounds Weird I know,  and 1 more thing when I select a row that contains an Image already , it works fine, I mean the image src shows me the source of the image in that selected row .

***

```
        <div ng-app="myTable1" ng-controller="myTable1_cont">
            <table class="table table-striped" id="mera_table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>S.no</th>
                    <th>I.D</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Buttons</th>
                </tr>

                </thead>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in names " id="myRow">
                    <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{x._id}}</td>
                    <td><img src={{x._img_url}}></td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="myFunc(this)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--end Table-->
        </div>
    </div><!--end table1 row-->

<button id="btn"> click</button>
</div><!--end container-->


<script>
    var app = angular.module('myTable1', []);
    app.controller('myTable1_cont', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://www.shreyansh.zz.mu/final/index.php/Admin_Panel/read_exercise_detail")
                .success(function (response) {
                    // $scope.names = response.records;
                    var b=JSON.parse(response.message);
                    console.log(b[4]);
                    $scope.names = b;
                });
    });


</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       console.log("yo");


    });

</script>


<!--Edit Button-->
<script >
    function myFunc(a){

        var c= a.parentNode.parentNode.localName;//tr
        var c1= a.parentNode.parentNode;//tr

        var x1=c1.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
        var x2=c1.getElementsByTagName('td')[2];


        var x9=x1.firstChild;
       var x10=x9.src;
       console.log("value of x10 is :"+x2.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src);
        console.log("--->"+x2.innerText);

    }
</script><!--Ends myFunc()-->***
```

Comment: What i really expect, is that when the image source is empty , it should also show , empty on clicking "EDIT" button, this is the normal behaviour that  i expect , but its showing me url of my own page

Comment: Use `ng-src` instead of `src` attribute. That way, AngularJS will parse the URL before the page attempts to assign the URL to the image. This will also ensure that when the URL is undefined or does not exist, the image src will also reflect accordingly.

Comment: Thanks  , it worked, just like you explained , unable to mark your comment as answer

Comment: I have provided my comment as answer. Kindly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-src` directive. From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Certain servers, by default, tend to return the base file (usually named index.html) when they cannot find the requested path.

Thus, since you used the image URL directly in the `src` attribute of the image tag, before AngularJS could get its hands on it, the browser already parsed the URL. Thus, the browser seemed to request the path `/{{_x.img_url}}` instead of the parsed angular expression. This caused the server to respond with the base file where you observed that the image was instead the web page itself.

Use `ng-src` and it solves your problem. AngularJS will parse the expression and replace the `src` attribute correctly just as you expect.